# What is the meaning of AUTO_INCREMENT=20018215 here in table schema

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

```
CREATE TABLE `tblspmaster` (
  `CSN` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SP` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `FileImportedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `AMZFileName` varchar(580) NOT NULL,
  `CasperBatch` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `BatchProcessedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `ExpiryDate` date NOT NULL,
  `Region` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `FCCity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `VendorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LocationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CSN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20018215 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What is the meaning of AUTO_INCREMENT=20018215 here in table schema . as i am inserting `500k` records my identity is OK from 1 to `500k` but when i tried to insert next `500k` records, next records identity column value is `524281` instead of `500001`.

Comment: Are you sure that happened? See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/025d8/1

Comment: i am surprised as its showing 1 for me in CSN column for first value and its works in auto increment fashion till 500k but when i start second insert process then its creating a gape of around 24 k numbers .

Comment: Maybe a trigger on your table?

Comment: no trigger :( .................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the first auto-assigned value (to `CSN`) will be 20018215

Comment: its starting from 1 but creating problem for me after 500k records.

Comment: @rahularyansharma:- Are you sure that you are using the same script for creating the table??

Comment: @rahularyansharma:- The max value of auto increment is   of 18446744073709551615. So definitely you cant have a range problem!!!

Comment: @rahularyansharma check your database for the DDL. In MySQL workbench you do it by `right-clicking on the table -> copy to clipboard -> create statement`

Comment: So either you're inserting/looking at the wrong table or you're missing something cause it obviously work as @juergen d [*already mentioned*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/025d8/1)

Answer (score 0):

The large initial value, 20018215, was probably the previous value of the auto increment when you did a "Send to SQL Editor" -> "Create Statement" menu selection in MySQL Workbench.  This is just a safe value to skip over existing data just in case you have to reimport the previous records.

I had the same question, but after generating several "Create" edit templates from known tables, I noticed the AUTO_INCREMENT value corresponded to the quantity of existing records in those tables.  I removed the large values from my templates since I want my new tables to begin with a primary key = 1.